# Element by class returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to simply get the number of users on a subredit.
When I open the HTML, I can see it.

```
<div class="_3XFx6CfPlg-4Usgxm0gK8R">55.3k</div>
```

I wrote a bit of python code to try and get the number:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/TowerofGod/"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

regulars = soup.find("div", class_ = "_3XFx6CfPlg-4Usgxm0gK8R")

print(regulars)
```

But I only get `None` as a response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any div with such class in the response. You should probably use API to achieve your goals.

Comment: @stardust its because its dynamically generated in each render!

Comment: @SebastianCristiCastillo I can find an object with the same class when I inspect the page manually, and it does not seem to generate a new class on every reload actually :)

Comment: its not exactly in "each" render, the page use static generation, and will return the page from server side.
If i search for the page now, i will not get that div class, if you do it in a hour or tomorrow, couldnt too.

Comment: Have a look at reddit's API, makes like much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is dynamically generated each time, so each time it will change and you will not be able to get it by that exact string.

How to do it?

Reddit offers you a json version of the page!
Only putting a .json at the end of the url, it will serve you with all the data of the subreddit, even posts!

example for the url:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/TowerofGod.json
```

if you see inside the data, you will find the element: `subreddit_subscribers   55389` (its a little inside of children and the data, but hey, the exact same as the sub have!)

in the json the steps to get to the element:

`response -> children -> 0 -> data -> subreddit_subscribers`